# cmake.cmakePath in vscode not setting path to desired cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have installed CMake through mingw64 using `pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` at location *C:\msys64\mingw64\bin* and am specifying the same in my `settings.json` of vscode as `"cmake.cmakePath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cmake.exe"`

but **Cmake: Delete cache and reconfigure** picks up cmake at location of  *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe*

How can I configure vscode `cmake.cmakePath`?